# Builder NE and NUnit

Tags: c#, matlab

We are experiencing problems when running a DLL that was created with MATLAB Builder NE in a NUnit test. However, if we reference the same project from a Console App it runs just fine. It seems like the problems stem from the NUnit environment.

Here is the error code:

```
Error marshalling .NET object.
'Message: Unable to find assembly 'Test.Miros.Plugins.Processors.Matlab, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
Source: mscorlib
HelpLink: '
```

Here is the source code:

```
[TestFixture]
public class MatlabProcessorTest
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        MirMat01DotNet.MirMat mirmat = new MirMat();

        mirmat.MirMat01(@"D:\Matlab\IniFiles\test.ini", new MWObjectArray(new MyTest()));
        var result = mirmat.BuilderFunctionTest(6, 3, 4);

        int k = 0;
    }
}
```

The MATLAB function is MirMat01 and has 2 input parameters: an ini file as well as a C# object. We can run the Test() method outside of of NUnit, but not as a test NUnit. It seems like the custom object (MyTest) is causing the issues.

Also, if we run the MirMat01 function with a standard C# object, like for instance a String object, then it runs fine as a NUnit test.

So it seems like NUnit is doing something that the DLL from Builder NE does not like. Has anyone experienced this behavior before? Any tips will be much appreciated :)

Kind regards
Anton

Comment: I have the same problem, but from MSTest. My code works fine outside a test class but I get the following errors from inside a [TestMethod]...   "Error marshalling .NET object" and "Type XYZ in assembly ABC is not marked as serializable. It's correct - the .NET object is not serializable so why does this work outside the test environment? Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I have gotten around this problem, with MSTest, my switching on deployment in the MStest settings and adding the bin folder to the list of deployment folders. Don't know why this is required for matlab tests but it works.

Comment: An alternative to turning on the deployment option (which is very slow) is to add an app.config to your test assembly which tells .NET where to find the matlab dlls...

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
 <runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
   <probing privatePath="x64"/>
  </assemblyBinding>
 </runtime>
</configuration>